# Fragment with colorful gradient using WEBGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

[Webgl practice problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be4Cl.jpg)

The practice problem I have to create is the image above and I can't figure out how to execute it. Every time I do I get a white screen. I know it has something to do with me adding the colors variable to a buffer attribute but I just can't figure it out. Any help will be grateful.

```js
var gl;

window.onload = function init()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    // Four Vertices

    var vertices = [
        vec2( -0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec2( -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec2(  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec2(  0.5, -0.5)
    ];


    var colors = [
        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // white
        1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // red
        0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // green
        0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // blue
    ];
    //
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );


   var colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);



    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer


    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    render();
};


function render() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4 );
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided us  [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Using `new` here looks like a bug, also there's nothing to flatten as the color array is already flat (btw. there's a official [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) function).

Also you still need to setup the vertex attribute like you do with position (keep in mind that your colors have more elements that your position) and output the color in the shader.